# how can I delete from 2 tables with condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to build a query to delete data from 2 tables but wiht some conditions like if the cree_facture.refe ='EST1' delete from cree_devis whith cree_devis.refe='EST1' and if the refe ='INV1' delete from cree_facture with the cree_facture.refe='INV1'

I try with this 2 query bu the problem delete all data from table not has the condition

```
DELETE FROM `cree_devis`, `cree_facture` 
USING `cree_devis`,`cree_facture` 
WHERE `cree_devis`.`cree_par` = `cree_facture`.`cree_par` 
  AND (`cree_devis`.`refe` = 'INV1'  OR `cree_facture`.`refe` = 'INV1' )
```

and

```
DELETE cree_devis, cree_facture 
FROM cree_devis 
INNER JOIN cree_facture ON (cree_devis.cree_par=cree_facture.cree_par)
WHERE cree_devis.refe = 'EST1' 
OR cree_facture.refe = 'EST1';
```

Comment: And what is the issue with running two queries for this?

Comment: to delete from two tables if the refe existe  eache of one

Comment: maybe you can include some sample data and desire output to help us understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you can not delete in 2 tables at the same time using a join.

You probably want this:

DELETE FROM CREE_DAVIS T1
WHERE T1.REFE = 'EST1'
  AND EXISTS
      (SELECT 1
         FROM CREE_FACTURE T2
        WHERE T1.CREE_PAR = T2.CREE_PAR
          AND T2.REFE = 'EST1')

Explaining: Delete from Table 1 every row for which there exists a row with matching CREE_PAR in the other table, while both have REFE = 'EST1'

Hope this is what you want.

You can now also make the other delete in the same way, using INV1 and changing the table names in the inner and outer query.

Comment: wont work cus after you delete em from the first table there will be nothing to comapre the second table to.

Comment: In this case it does. As first query uses different argument EST1 while second uses INV1. If arguments had been the same you are right.

Comment: thanks for aal I sloved the problem wiht the if condition if string = EST deletete from 1 table and if string= INV delete from second table easy and siple